# ASP - New instance of SQL database per user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I have been struggling with this for some time, and can't seem to find any info.

I have created an online point of sales system using an SQL database, EntityFramework, ASP and .Net4 in C#. My previous programming experience has been with OpenGL and DirectX, so this is all very new to me.

Users from a single company will log into the site using a single account. They can then use the online till and backoffice. Thus far the software has been developed using a single SQL database. What I would like to do is have the application create and use a different instance of the SQL database per account.

Does this sound sensible/possible, or would you expect to have a single huge database for all users? - Note: there could potentially be a huge number of users which each store a lot of information and each user will only need access to their own database.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: This seems like overkill to me - most mature databases can handle a very large amount of data with no problems so I really don't think you will have any problems but as above it is hard to say much more without knowing what database you are using? SQL Server? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this sound sensible/possible, or would you expect to have a
>   single huge database for all users? - Note: there could potentially be
>   a huge number of users which each store a lot of information and each
>   user will only need access to their own database.

This is possible, but it is not at all sensible. Users don't access databases, applications do. Separating a full database per user only makes sense if your application is offering users the capability of creating their own data structures within the application (such as a hosting provider would do). If it is simply meant to house multiple identical structures keyed off each user, then you'll be better off spending your time normalizing a proper relational structure (an assumption since you mentioned you're using SQL) and optimizing queries/stored procedures to make data retrieval/insertion fast.

RDBMS is perfectly capable of handling huge amounts of users and large subsets of data if you normalize it effectively keying each structure appropriately (in most cases by the userkey).

Comment: +1 - and there are ways to provide custom fields for individual users with-in single database

Comment: Thanks - So a single database is sounding like the most sensible option, but what about security? Can users have access restricted to only read entries related to them?

The plan was to offer a backup facility and be able to restore individual users data to a previous state. With separate databases this would just involve keeping an archive of their database. Can this be achieved with a single database solution?

Comment: @user1374841: With having records normalized by user key, permission to records can be restricted in any number of ways. This restriction becomes controlled at the application level rather than at the database level, however. Backups can still be achieved, but I don't have the dba experience to suggest an appropriate method.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not a good approach, as if there will be any scheme changes in you will have to keep synchronize each database instance.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to have a single huge database for all users.

SQL Server will only support 32,767 databases per instance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx